# TASM: Embedded Loops

Tags: loops, nested-loops, tasm

does anybody knows what's the syntax for double looping in TASM? I remember you use cx with push and pop function but I don't remember how.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi @Alvizouri, you seem new here, so I think I should mention that it's generally considered good form to "accept" an answer that solves your problem. You can do that by clicking the "tick" next to the answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how

```
    mov cx, 02           ; loop twice
    cc:                  ; outer  loop
    push cx              ; store outer cx
    mov cx,03            ; loop thrice
    bb:                  ; inner loop

    ;do stuff

    loop bb
    pop cx               ;get outer cx
    loop cc
```

that's basically it