# Loop statement in assembly error

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm

I've built an assembly program and when I try to loop a label, compile (with 0 errors) and execute, I get this error :

```
    ntvdm cpu has encountered an illegal instruction
```

So I remove the code into the label, but i still get that error!
And if I remove the loop statement, the program works

Haven't the loop statement the following sintax?

```
    mov  cx,5
    loop foo
    ;execute foo  5 times
```

Comment: foo: is under the loop statement

Comment: It should be before if I recall correctly ( for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849606/tasm-embedded-loops ).

Comment: ok, thanks..but how far can it be? And another thing...it must be between the cx assignment and the loop statement?

Comment: The posted answer should show you.  I don't know what you mean by "how far can it be" - I don't really see how distance in terms of lines of assembly would impact this but if I'm wrong I'd appreciate correction.

Comment: @SubSevn: It does matter (indirectly), since destination address is expressed as a signed 8-bit offset relative to the current instruction pointer. This allows offsets in the range -128..127.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where's "foo"?

Should be something like:

```
mov cx,5
foo:
;do stuff
loop foo
```

Comment: foo: is under the loop statement

Comment: That's your problem then.  That's not how it works.  :-)

Comment: It's entirely possible to `loop` forward, although that isn't the most common scenario.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to loop is `jmp` statement, which has many types eg: je , jg , jnz , jz e.t.c.

```
mov cx,5;let you want to loop 5 time, move 5 in cx
jmp foo; jumping to foo

;some stuff if you want

foo:

     ;do some thing you want

dec cx;decrease cx by 1
jnz foo; jump to foo if value of cx is not zero
```

; when value is zero loop will end,any thing further you want to do after loop will comes here